# How can I sort a secondary column in dataGridView?

Tags: sorting, datagridview

I have a datagridview that I am looking to sort. One column is headed "Page" which is a number 2-3 digits long. I have another column called "Item" which is a number between 1 and 3. I am trying to sort the data by both, page first and then item:

(example)

```
Page 01, item 1
Page 01, item 2
Page 02, item 2
Page 02, item 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a little old but I came here looking for answers and no one else had responded, so I thought i'd put one up here.

First thing you need to do is disable the automatic sort on the header.  After I bind the datasource to the dgv i call a disableSort method, which I actually found works best by setting sort mode to programmatic

```
    private void disableSort()
    {
        foreach(DataGridViewColumn dc in dataGridView2.Columns)
        {
            dc.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
        }
    }
```

Then i tied into the CellMouseDown event on the dataGrid

```
        private void dataGridView2_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1)
        {
            int rIdx = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            seq = dataGridView2.Rows[rIdx].Cells["SequenceNo"].Value.ToString();

            int selectedColumnIdx = e.ColumnIndex;
            ListSortDirection direction;

            if (dataGridView2.SortedColumn == dataGridView2.Columns[selectedColumnIdx])
            {
                if (dataGridView2.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
                {
                    direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
                }
                else
                {
                    direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            }

            this.dataGridView2.Sort(this.dataGridView2.Columns["SequenceNo"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            this.dataGridView2.Sort(this.dataGridView2.Columns[selectedColumnIdx], direction);
        }
```

if you go in through the ColumnHeaderMouseClick event you can skip my RowIndex check

I'm using SequenceNumber as my secondary sort (after the user selects a column to sort, they want it to be sorted by sequenceNumber).  Just figure out which column the user is sorting, what its current sortorder is, take the opposite, then sort your secondary column first, then your primary.